# Convert [NSFileWrapper initDirectoryWithFileWrappers] to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, nsfilewrapper

I have following Objective-C code:

```
NSFileWrapper* fileWrapper;
NSMutableDictionary* wrappers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
...
fileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc]
                   initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:wrappers];
```

I tried to convert above code to Swift:

```
var fileWrapper : NSFileWrapper?
let wrappers = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: [:])
....
fileWrapper = NSFileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: wrappers)
```

the last line cannot be compiled. I got error message saying

> Cannot convert value type of 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected argument type '[String : NSFileWrapper]'

I am not sure what is type of `[String : NSFileWrapper]`, a list? Is there anyway to convert wrappers to this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSFileWrapper` initializer has changed to take in a Swift dictionary rather than an `NSDictionary`:

```
public class NSFileWrapper : NSObject, NSCoding {

    // ....

    public init(directoryWithFileWrappers childrenByPreferredName: [String : NSFileWrapper])

    // ....
}
```

`[String : NSFileWrapper]` is Swift syntax for a dictionary where `String` is the type of the key and `NSFileWrapper` is the type of the value for that key.

Just use Swift types:

Swift 3:

```
FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
```

Swift 2.x:

```
var fileWrapper : NSFileWrapper?
let wrappers: [String : NSFileWrapper] = [:]
fileWrapper = NSFileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: wrappers)
```

Comment: Not much point declaring a constant for an empty dictionary literal. Just do FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:]) (the NS was removed in Swift 3)

Comment: @Ash Thanks this was an old answer written in Swift 2.x to match the asker.  Updated the answer to Swift 3.